# Auto resizing NSBox

Tags: cocoa, containstable, nsbox

I have `NSBox` with `NSTableView` siting inside it. I have disabled the scrolling in the table and trying to auto resize the NSBox to mach the number of entries in NSTableView but don't know how to...any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this automatically, you will need to write code that monitors the size of the table view and then resizes the box to match.

This sounds like an odd UI, what are you trying to achieve?